# Why does the page scroll up after each slideDown and how to prevent this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a couple of `jQuery slideDown` functions, which I use to show `Divs` once the user clicked a `button`.

The problem is that after clicking the button the page `scroll up` to the top and the `Divs` are not visible anymore. What I would like to do is, preventing the page from scrolling. How can I fix this?

jQuery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#banner_step_3").hide();
$("#next_btn_show_step_3").click(function(){
    $("#banner_step_3").slideDown(500);
  });
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="next_btn" id="next_btn_show_step_3">
    <a href="#"><?php echo $lang ['next']; ?></a>
</div>
<article class="order_form_step_3" id="banner_step_3">
</article>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser is simply following the link.

Use [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) or `return false` to stop it continuing with the default behaviour.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#banner_step_3").hide();
$("#next_btn_show_step_3").click(function(e){
    $("#banner_step_3").slideDown(500);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Cancel the click event with preventDefault()

```
$("#next_btn_show_step_3").click( function (evt) {
    $("#banner_step_3").slideDown(500);
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

replace:

```
<a href="#"><?php echo $lang ['next']; ?></a>
```

with:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"><?php echo $lang ['next']; ?></a>
```

when you create an `<a>` tag with `href="#"`, it will always redirect to the top of the page, cause the browser is actually browsing to the href you provided.

**alternatively**, you can block this action (jump to top) within the **javascript function**. make the following changes:

```
$("#next_btn_show_step_3").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#banner_step_3").slideDown(500);
});
```

hope that helps.